# Remove Auto mount of linux drive/partition on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, multi-boot, centos-5

I have a Snow Leopard + CentOS dual boot system setup. When I log in to Snow Leopard, it tells me that it is unable to mount the disk that i have just inserted. It is referring to my centos partitions. It gives me the option to initialize or ignore. I would rather that never come up incase I accidentally erase my linux partitions.

I tried to follow the instructions on http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060930150059172

It advices to create /etc/fstab and add noauto at the end

> UUID=F0E430C1-5558-3BB3-9FA9-6904B663FEEA  none  hfs  rw,noauto

However, I can't find the UUID or the volume label on the linux drives/partitions. I tried diskutil info /dev/disk1
diskutil info /dev/disk1s1

I looked in system.log; There is no UUID it seems. Where can I find it? And if I can't, can I use /dev/disk1s1 in /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

synchronizing mbr and gpt did not work, and reformatting didn't work.

I ended up using OSXFuse http://osxfuse.github.com/ and was then able to tell it to not automount.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)? I wouldn't dual boot a Mac without it:

[image: Screenshot from rEFIt boot menu]

It [has an option to synchronize the MBR and GPT](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c2s3_shell.html) partition tables - it's just conjecture, but this might solve your problem.

On a secondary note, it's very unobtrusive and comes with a complete uninstall guide - so an attempt shouldn't hurt your system.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do have refit installed and I synchronized them. The linux partitions are in lvm. I'll try to convert to non-lvm and then try to sync the partitions again to test.

Answer (score 0):

According to the thread [Ext4 partition: Getting rid of Initialize, Ignore or Eject](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=249096), this may be
happening because the CentOS partition is formatted as ext4.

Reformatting it as ext3 should solve the problem.